# Sum products in certain conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm sorry to ask this, I have not any code skills and I've trying to figure that out for a few hours now.. I think an image will be better for you to understand what I want:
[image]

I want A2 to show the sum of the products in G:G that fit certain conditions (2020,jan,buy). I haved tried several formulas but I came up with this one as the closest, I think, but still won't work:

```
=arrayformula(SUMIFS(E:E=B1,F:F="jan",G:G="buy",H:H))
```

Can anyone explain me how to achieve that?
Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this formula in A2 it will work

```
=sumifs(G2:G100,D2:D100,2020,E2:E100,"jan",F2:F100,"buy")
```

So basically, sumifs formula is right one as you want to check for multiple conditions.
so this is how this formula work

```
=sumifs(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2,...)
```

In your case your same range is column 'G' so if you have a finite range like only 25 rows you have in your table then instead of G2:G100 you can use G2:G25 as G1 is containing label and make sure that all other ranges also similar to the range of column G. for example if you take range of G2:G100 means 99 rows then you should take E2:E100 or E3:E101(range of 99 rows, that rows must be 99 and series start and end number is as per your requirement, similar case for other columns in this formula)

you have to check 2020 in column D, so you criteria_range1 is of D column I took it D2:D100 and criteria 1 is 2020 as it's a number it doesn't need double quotes
criteria 2 is you need to check Jan in column E so criteria_range2 is column E I took it E2:E100 and criteria 2 is "jan" as it's not a number so I took it in double quotes.
criteria 3 is you need to check 'buy' in column F so Criteria_range3 is column F. I took it as F2:F100 and criteria 3 is "buy" again it's not a number so took it under double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much Kedar, that was exactly what I've been looking for, plus, I Learned with your explanation.